# drupal theming filter for a view

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views, drupal-theming

I am trying to change the theme for my exposed filters for a particular view by overriding the views-exposed-form.tpl.php.
The problem I am having is that I cannot seem to get the naming convention of the view set up correctly - I have been trying to use views-exposed-form--viewname--displayname.tpl.php, but that is not being found.  I thought I could choose Theme:Information from within the view to see what theme file is currently being used, but there is not section for views-exposed-form.tpl.php.

Do I have to make any modification to Theme.inc?
Does anyone know why that does not exist under Theme: Information?
Thanks for any thoughts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.  I thought I could create the new tpl files within the module, but they had to go into the views folder for the theme - not the module.

Thanks